# cur = mysql.connection.cursor() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, flask, pythonanywhere

Залил на хостинг(pythonanywhere) свой сайт.
Создал на нём базу данных mysql, взял пароль, хост, юзер, имя базы.
Но вылазит ошибка 'NoneType' has no attribute 'cursor'
Вот код:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, flash, request, g, redirect, jsonify
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'NAME.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'USERNAME'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'PASSWORD'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'USERNAME$DBNAME'

mysql = MySQL(app)

def conn():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    return cur

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def ind():
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == "POST":
        date = request.form.get('fieldname')
        # try:
        cur = conn()
        cur.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rews(
                reviews TEXT
            )
        ''')
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.execute("SELECT reviews FROM rews")
        result = cur.fetchall()
        result_string = '; '.join([item[0] for item in result])
        print(result)
        cur.close()
        return render_template('landing.html', date=date, rew=result_string)
        # except:
        #     return render_template('landing.html', date=date, rew='К сожалению в БД произошла ошибка. Мы попытаемся это исправить :(')
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/add-think', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def add():
    data = request.get_json()
    re_data = data['cback']
    print(re_data)
    try:
        cur = conn()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO rews (reviews) VALUES (%s)", (re_data,))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        return jsonify('Успешно!')
    except:
        return jsonify('Ошибка.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```